# Однозначно ли то, что "пройти через войну" является речевой ошибкой, и надо писать "пройти войну"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я вижу логику в том, что пройти через войну подразумевает главным образом "препятствие", а если опустить "через" мы говорим об опыте, полученном человеком

Answer (score 1):

Оба выражения корректны, но различаются по смыслу, поэтому о речевой ошибке речь может идти при неправильном контестном употреблении.

"**Прошёл войну**" обычно означает "**воевал**, (провоевал всю войну, большую её часть)",  а "**прошёл через войну**" - шире по смыслу и значит "***прошел через испытания**, связанные с войной*" (не обязательно воевал, но был в оккупации, в плену, голодал, трудился в тяжелых условиях).

Речевой ошибкой было бы сказать "прошёл войну" (вместо "... через войну") о человеке, всю войну прожившем в оккупации, какой бы тяжелой ни была его судьба.